How to manage timeouts in Laravel Backpack
I am importing a CSV of contacts using a controller in Backpack for Laravel (5). In that process I use the Google Places API to validate the address and get back it's components.
With larger CSVs this can take some time and the browser ends up showing the following error after 2 mins:

Request Timeout This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact
administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

I am hoping to allow this process to take as long as it needs to run. It runs in real time with a progress bar for the end user.
I tried the following:

To add set_time_limit(0); within the function in the controller that manages the portion with Google Places.

Set the following in my cPanel PHP settings:

max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600


Set the following in the .htaccess file:

Timeout 600
KeepAliveTimeout 600
ProxyTimeout 600


Set 'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 600), in config/session.php


The weird thing is that even though that error is shown, the data carries on getting processed in the background.

wouldn't it be better to just implement a better solution? upload the file, and let queue process it, then report the update via websocket

I figured it out. By adding the following code in my .htaccess file in the folder of my Laravel project (not the root folder one), the script will not be timed out.
RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1]
RewriteRule .* - [E=noconntimeout:1]
SetEnv noconntimeout 1

